# Save nested Solve results into variables (edited)

Tags: equation-solving, variable-definitions

I have some solve results stored in the ptes variable:

```
ptes = Solve[{x1, y1} \[Element] 
lin[alpha0, p1x0] && {x1, y1} \[Element] rec1, {x1, y1}]

{{x1 -> -80.0104, y1 -> -7.}, {x1 -> 0, y1 -> 0}}
```

I would like to store those 4 numbers into 4 different variables. I have been trying to access them in the following manner:

```
p1tes = Part[ptes, 1];
p2tes = Part[ptes, 2];
```

and then the single values

```
p1xtes = p1tes[[1]]
p1ytes = p1tes[[2]]
p2xtes = p2tes[[1]]
p2ytes = p2tes[[2]]
```

however now in these variables is stored something like

```
x1 -> -80.0104
```

I don't know how to store only the value, which I would need to perform some calculation afterward. I have tried reading some similar questions here, but for some reason they do not apply to my case

Thanks

Comment: To get the order of the variables right, start with `sol = {x1,y1} /. ptes` and then extract numbers from `sol`, for example with `{p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y}=Flatten[sol]`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/26598

Comment: @Roman thanks, this solved my issue. I'd like to mark the answer as solved, but it doesn't allow me to do so, I suspect it is because your is a comment and not an answer

Comment: `Values@Solve[(y^2 + x^2) == 25 && x + y == 7, {x, y}]` Use `Flatten` if you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a simple example

```
Solve[(y^2 + x^2) == 25 && x + y == 7, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 3, y -> 4}, {x -> 4, y -> 3}}

What you are looking for is

```
{x, y} /. Solve[(y^2 + x^2) == 25 && x + y == 7, {x, y}]
```

> {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}

which you can save in a variable.